# emacs+geben how do I open a file to put breakpoints in it

Tags: emacs, geben

When I'm debugging code in a framework, it usually goes through a bunch of different calls in different files before actually getting to the file I want to investigate.  Is there a way to open the file I want when I start geben, put the breakpoint in that file then tell geben to run (press g)?

Otherwise I have to keep stepping over/into until geben finally get's to the file I want, at which point I can then go to the line I want and set the breakpoint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> runs `geben-find-file`

IIRC, geben must already be in an active debugging session for that function to work; but once set the breakpoints are persistent, so it's not too onerous.

`geben-breakpoint-menu` menu is very convenient for setting conditionals, if you hadn't noticed that.

Comment: Any idea why this fails when debugging on a remote host? The prompt proposes something like `/nil:...` which doesn't work... Substituting 'nil' with a proper '/ssh...' chain fails as well with something like 'Wrong type argument: plistp,' :-(

Comment: No, but if you're not already using the fork from https://github.com/ahungry/geben then try that.  If the same problem occurs, check the issue queue there, and raise a bug report if necessary.